# Laravel 10: Class "League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\PortableVisibilityConverter" not found

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, composer-php

in my prod environment I'm having this error while locally everything works perfectly.

I don't know what's wrong with it. I suspect there are some problem related to composer but it's not clear to me how to fix this.

As suggested in Laravel I have installed:
`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0" --with-all-dependencies`

I've also try `composer dump-autoload` and as last chance I've fully removed the vendor folder and `composer install` but the problem persist.

This is the composer output:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   INFO  Discovering packages.

  anhskohbo/no-captcha .................................................................................................................... DONE
  barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ............................................................................................................. DONE
  intervention/image ...................................................................................................................... DONE
  laravel/tinker .......................................................................................................................... DONE
  nesbot/carbon ........................................................................................................................... DONE
  nunomaduro/collision .................................................................................................................... DONE
  nunomaduro/termwind ..................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-ignition ................................................................................................................. DONE

90 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
No security vulnerability advisories found
```

Ideas?

Comment: Did you check whether this class exists at the path it should exist at? Also, is this really a problem related to S3?

Comment: What code causes the error to be triggered?

Answer (score 3):

Just running `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0" --with-all-dependencies` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to generate an ide-helper.php file for development and realized that I was using the s3 filesystem driver. In other words, I had "FILESYSTEM_DISK=s3" in my .env.

I changed the driver to "FILESYSTEM_DISK=local" to generate the ide-helper.php file and changed it back to s3 afterward as I am intending to use s3 later but do not want to install dependencies at this stage.

I believe the reason this worked was that ide-helper only includes those aws dependencies if you are using the s3 driver.

If you are using s3 as your driver in production then this will obviously not work.

It is not clear in your post if you are using ide-helper but you should not use it in production.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if there is a package in `vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`. Packages are often cached, but the physical presence of a package on disk can tell you for sure that it is not a cache.
2. Delete the **vendor** folder. Run `composer install` again. Check for the package in vendor. Reinstall to make sure the installation is correct and there are no errors with PHP language dependencies (modules).  You can try to remove the package `composer remove league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` separately.
3. if you are using **docker** - run `composer install` **INSIDE** the container.

Comment: What do you mean by "check for the package"? What **exactly** should be checked? And why should removing the vendor folder once more (which was already done!) resolve the problem?

Comment: packages are often cached, but the physical presence of a package on disk can tell you for sure that it is not a cache.

reinstall to make sure the installation is correct and there are no errors with PHP language dependencies (modules). You can try to remove the package `composer remove league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` separately.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it